# Targeting a form using Mechanize and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Note: It seems the page was built using Angular.js so maybe that is what is causing a problem??? I have tried many different ways to target a form that is shown on this page:
"https://use-manager.com/#!/signin".  For some reason, no forms are found when I try to find them via normal methods such as:

```
 @form = @page.form_with(class: "signin")
```

or even

```
@form = @page.forms.first
```

What is even more odd to me is that if I simply do:

```
@page = @agent.get('https://use-manager.com')
```

and then display the pages body in the view:

```
<%= @page.body.inspect %>
```

The form is still nowhere to be found...

Nothing is able to locate the form for some reason...Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: that site is .js-heavy, and mechanize doesn't support javascript.  You may want to investigate a webdriver-based solution (e.g. selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, etc.).

Comment: Thanks I just started looking into that.  I guess Mechanize is a no go for this one? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspecting the elements, we find the following:

```
 <input aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-touched" id="username" name="username" data-ng-model="credentials.username" type="text">
```

Password:

```
<input id="password" class="ng-pristine ng-valid md-input ng-touched" type="password" data-ng-model="credentials.password" name="password" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false"></input>
```

Button:

```
<button class="md-button md-default-theme" ng-transclude="" type="submit">
```

Clicking the button after filling in the user / password submits the following JSON (as a POST to https://use-manager.com/auth/signin)

```
{"username":"testing","password":"123"}
```

So if I were you, I would skip worrying about filling in the form and just do a JSON post to the signin page and take it from there.

There also appears to be an alternate login page here:

[Login](https://www.use-manager.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.use-manager.com%2Fauth%2Fsignin)

That has a form...

```
<form method="post" action="login;jsessionid=5B1002FE04FDBDC6B0D00C0949EDE75F?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.use-manager.com%2Fauth%2Fsignin" name="login">

                                    <input name="action" value="do_login" type="hidden">
                                        <input name="urlparams" value="" type="hidden">

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label>Username&nbsp;</label>                                       
                                            <input id="username" class="textbox" name="username" size="32" tabindex="1" accesskey="n">

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label>Password &nbsp;</label>
                                            <input class="textbox" id="password" name="password" size="32" tabindex="2" accesskey="p" type="password">                                                                                      
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="remember">
                                          <input name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" value="true" type="checkbox"> 
                                          <label for="rememberMe">Remember Me</label>
                                        </div> 

                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="http://www.use-group.com/use-manager-support.html" target="_blank">Trouble logging in?</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="javascript:forgotpwd()">Forgot Password?</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <div class="row btn-row">
                                            <input name="lt" value="_c316E91C9-E9CC-CB77-9C3F-1D94EC1A5AF3_kB493A777-3227-2796-6E52-DC8BA896B36D" type="hidden">
                                            <input name="_eventId" value="submit" type="hidden">

                                            <input class="submit" name="bttn1" onclick="callBldg(document.forms[0].username.value)" accesskey="l" value="LOGIN" tabindex="4" type="button">
                                            <input class="submit" name="reset" accesskey="c" value="CLEAR" tabindex="5" type="reset">
                                        </div>

                                </form>
```

Comment: OOoo cool idea.  I'll try this as soon as I get home and if it works I owe you a hi-five!

Comment: You sir, are a champion.